# laravel file uploading using json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. I have did the following code to post data using json to my controller. But I cannot make file uploading by this manner.

```
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: 'tasks',
    data: $('#my_form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

I have the following html code to upload files.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="documents[]" multiple>
```

How can I send file using json in laravel? I have did many search but I cant get proper solution

Comment: Either use the normal submit of an html form, or use FormData instead of serialize, this doesn't work in version 9 or older of IE though

Comment: Could you explain this please? I don't know how to do that?

Comment: sorry for late answer, added some code as answer as to how to use formdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as your code:

```
e.preventDefault();
var mydata = new FormData($('#my_form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: 'tasks',
    data: mydata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: flase
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

Note that this doesn't work on some older browsers such as IE 9 or older so you might need to disabled this feature to prevent your errorlogs from overloading, I give my users a custom message that the feature is disabled in older browsers by using

```
if(typeof FormData !== 'undefined'){
   var formdata = new FormData($("#documentform")[0]);
}
else{
   $("#errormsg").val("upload feature is disabled in this browser version");
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard jquery ajax don't support directly the sending of files. To do it, you basicly need too use the `FormData` object instead of a standard js one for your post parameter collection.

You will also need to disable 2 parametters in the ajax option :

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

to prevent jquery from interfering with the FormData Object.

More info here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/4734683